# Flutter Bloc 7.0.0 state not updating after migrate to null safety

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bloc

i've been trying to update state from bloc for hours and didnt work, i even try to check the properties of the state before yield and all properties is updated but the state wont.

here is my code

**Bloc**

```
  @override
  Stream<HomeState> mapEventToState(
    HomeEvent event,
  ) async* {
    if (event is HomeStarted) {
      yield HomeLoadSuccess(carts: []);
    }
    if (event is HomeCartAdded) {
      var currentState = state as HomeLoadSuccess;
      var carts = addCart(currentState.carts, event.item, event.qty);
      print(carts);
      //output carts working as expected but the state doesnt change/update
      //yield HomeInitial(); uncomment this line works but meh
      yield currentState.copyWith(carts: carts);
    }
  }
```

**Event**

```
abstract class HomeEvent {}

class HomeStarted extends HomeEvent {}

class HomeCartAdded extends HomeEvent {
  final Item item;
  final double qty;
  HomeCartAdded({required this.item, this.qty = 0.0});
}
```

**State**

```
abstract class HomeState extends Equatable {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class HomeInitial extends HomeState {}

class HomeLoadInProgress extends HomeState {}

class HomeLoadSuccess extends HomeState {
  final List<Cart> carts;

  HomeLoadSuccess({
    required this.carts,
  });

  HomeLoadSuccess copyWith({List<Cart>? carts}) {
    return HomeLoadSuccess(
      carts: carts ?? this.carts,
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [carts];
}
```

**Item Class**

```
class Item extends Equatable {
  int id;
  String name;
  String picture;
  double price;
  Item({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.picture,
    required this.price,
  });

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [id, name, picture, price];
}
```

**Cart Class**

```
//class item
class Cart extends Equatable {
  Item item;
  double qty;
  double total;
  Cart({
    required this.item,
    required this.qty,
    required this.total,
  });
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [item, qty, total];
}
```

is there anything wrong with my code or am i missing something here ?
im able to get this code working with prev version of bloc.. thanks

Comment: no errors shown in your debug console? Has this bloc worked fine before 7.0.0 update?

Comment: @SimonSot no errors, yes this code working with prev version of bloc 6.1.3, i dont think its bloc library that caused this. maybe flutter after upgrade, for now have to yield another state before yield the one mentioned above to get this code working.

Comment: Please join the LinkedIn group and share your Question link there for other developers to be notified: https://www.linkedin.com/groups/12438453/